# Coredata lightweight migration "Can't find mapping model for migration"

Tags: core-data-migration

I am doing a coredata database migration using lightweight migration in xcode4.5, I kept on getting "Can't find mapping model for migration" when I set "NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption" to "NO". If I set "NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption" to "YES", lightweight migration passes without problem.

Here is the steps I followed:

1. add a new model version .xcdatamodelId
2. make changes on the entities (including adding a new entity)
3. select the newer versioned datamodel as the current version, generate the new NSManagedObject subclasses, and make correspondant changes to the code.
4. create a mapping model and make the source points to the old datamodel version and the destination points to the new datamodel version
5. create custom migration policy and hook it up with one of the mappings inside the
   mapping model
6. set up lightweight migration with "NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption" equals to "NO".
7. test migration on simulator with the database coming from an older build.

I followed all and steps talked on apple documents and didn't make any changes on the entity schema after creating the mapping.. I tried to clean the DerivedData folder in xcode, and also I check the "VersionInfo.plist" which contains the correct versions of my datamodel. For the unchanged entities their hashkey are matching.

However I still get this error when I tried to do an migration.... Quite frustrated now.. Anyone can help to give me some guid on this problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out why this issue happened. It seems like using the auto generated mapping model results this error. If I remove the mappings for unchanged models from the mapping model file, the lightweight proceed successfully, my mappings and custom policy have been invoke.... So for now, I am using customized migration using "Migration Manager"